# what is the "count" in vim?

Tags: vim, vi

Seeing the help of vim I have problem to understand what refers the word ***count*** I see it many times while reading the manual:

```
i   Insert text before the cursor [count] times
```

It would be awesome if you give an example for it.

Comment: Try [`:help count`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#[count]).

Comment: @Kevin I am stupid but I missed it thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Vim's "Count" allows you to repeat an operator or command several times. For example, if you are on the first cursor of this line:

```
Hello world, how are you?
```

And you type `dw` you will have

```
world, how are you?
```

Rather than typing `dwdwdwdw`, you may simply type `4dw` or `d4w` and you will have

```
are you?
```

More specific to your example, you may type something like `5ihello<esc>` and this will insert

```
hellohellohellohellohello
```

Like Kevin said in a comment, you can read up more in the help docs with `:h count`, which says:

```
                                *count* *[count]*
    [count]     An optional number that may precede the command to multiply
            or iterate the command.  If no number is given, a count of one
            is used, unless otherwise noted.  Note that in this manual the
            [count] is not mentioned in the description of the command,
            but only in the explanation.  This was done to make the
            commands easier to look up.  If the 'showcmd' option is on,
            the (partially) entered count is shown at the bottom of the
            window.  You can use <Del> to erase the last digit (|N<Del>|).
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case somebody is wondering how `count` plus `insert` works, you have to type a number before pressing `i`, then it will enter in `insert mode`, where you can type what you want, after you press `esc` to go back to `normal mode`, it will repeat `count` times what you typed.

Answer (score -2):

Can you provide a link to the place in the documentation where you are confused? I would have posted this as a comment instead of an answer, but my reputation is not high enough. In attempting to answer your question without clarification:

- Usually [count] can be substituted with a number.
- For example; consider the delete command `d`. If you position your cursor in the middle of a text line and type `:d[count]` (ex: `:d4`) then press an arrow key (left or right arrow); you will end up deleting `[count]` (e.g. **4 characters**) in the corresponding direction of the arrow key.

In the case of `insert` I am not sure to what the argument`count` is referring.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that you must hit the `enter` key after `:d4`. Then press the left arrow key. Of course, in order for VIM to realize that you are entering a command you must exit *insert mode* by pressing the `esc` key prior to entering the command `:d4`.

Comment: If you type `:d4` and then left, your cursor will move to the `4` you just typed.

Comment: If you type `:d4` and then enter, vim will delete 4 lines. It doesn't matter what cursor keys you press after.

Comment: Try it in VIM. For the version of VIM i'm using (Vi IMproved 7.4) `:d4` and the left or right arrow key will delete **4 characters** left or right of the cursor. `:d4` and the up or down arrow key will delete **4 lines** up or down from the line of the cursor.

Comment: On my machine typing `::d4` accomplishes the behavior you are stating.

Comment: I tried it. I'm also using 7.4. Even the documentation contradicts you: `:[range]d[elete] [x] {count}     Delete {count} lines` - nothing about deleting characters in some direction.

Comment: You are correct in that `:[range]d[elete] [x] {count}` is in the documentation. But so is: `d {motion}` which "Deletes the text that {motion} moves over". See: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html

Comment: Yes, that's the `d` command in normal mode. But you said to type `:` first, which changes from normal to command-line mode. (And with normal mode commands, the count comes *first*: It's `[count]d`, not `d[count]`. `d4[whatever]` only works if `[whatever]` takes a count of 4 and does something sensible with it.)

Comment: True, that is an important distinction. Thank you for pointing that out. The point was simply to illustrate how `[count]` is used. Whether it be `[count]d` or `d[count]`, the example was only meant to show an appropriate usage of `[count]`; and demystify the documentation for those less experienced. I apologize if the above example failed to illustrate what `[count]` means in the context of the *delete* operation. My intent was simply to show how `[count]` can be used to parametrize operations in vim.